# Doctrine get all field names with associations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I already know how to get field names for entity, but how to get class names for all associations also?

```
$em->getClassMetadata('Product')->getFieldNames();
```

This gets class property only, but I expect to get association names inside nested array, for example if I have customer associated to product I would like to get all customer class property names too.

Comment: can't you iterate over the associations given and request their meta data as well?

Answer (score 14):

You can get the associated field names as well then merge them

```
$properties = $em->getClassMetadata('YourBundle:Product')->getFieldNames();
$output = array_merge(
              $properties, 
              $em->getClassMetadata('YourBundle:Product')->getAssociationNames()
);
```

Answer (score 4):

One liner:

```
array_keys($entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor($entity)->reflFields)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little hint.

I would prefer restructuring the way your organize your schema in order to properly retrieve all associated fields. For instance, according to this line of your question "if I have customer associated to product", I believe you have at least one-to-one or one-to-many relationship between customer and product. If you declare these relationships in your ORM, if you use YAML or annotations or any preferred/give way, you will be able to retrieve field names with a standard DQL query / or get methods.

The point to taken from here is, when you are expecting associating fields to be retrieved, it's best if you establish a solid database schema by providing relevant relationships at first place. This will reduce the job you have to do by half and will increase the performance in system/coding practice in long run.

Hope this helps,
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up merging them into one array by getting first each association name and then field names for each name.